# SQL Server 2008: How to query all databases sizes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have MS SQL 2008 R2, 500 databases.
What is the most efficient, easiest and 'modern' way to query all databases sizes.

The output should have columns:

- DatabaseName
- DataFilesSize
- LogFilesSize

Answer (score 240, accepted):

```
with fs
as
(
    select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 size
    from sys.master_files
)
select 
    name,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 0 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) DataFileSizeMB,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 1 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) LogFileSizeMB
from sys.databases db
```

Comment: @Derek Smith - size column is in pages. The size of one page is 8kB, hence the formula SizeInMb = PagesCount * 8 / 1024. I always believed 1MB = 1024kB. I don't think that even Microsoft has enough power to change this :).

Comment: This answer is reporting the wrong values for tempdb on our system for some reason. Please see [this related question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142076).

Answer (score 44):

I don't know exactly what you mean by efficiency but this is straightforward and it works for me:

```
SELECT
    DB_NAME(db.database_id) DatabaseName,
    (CAST(mfrows.RowSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 RowSizeMB,
    (CAST(mflog.LogSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 LogSizeMB,
    (CAST(mfstream.StreamSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 StreamSizeMB,
    (CAST(mftext.TextIndexSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 TextIndexSizeMB
FROM sys.databases db
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, SUM(size) RowSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE type = 0 GROUP BY database_id, type) mfrows ON mfrows.database_id = db.database_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, SUM(size) LogSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE type = 1 GROUP BY database_id, type) mflog ON mflog.database_id = db.database_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, SUM(size) StreamSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE type = 2 GROUP BY database_id, type) mfstream ON mfstream.database_id = db.database_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, SUM(size) TextIndexSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE type = 4 GROUP BY database_id, type) mftext ON mftext.database_id = db.database_id
```

With results like:

```
DatabaseName  RowSizeMB LogSizeMB StreamSizeMB TextIndexSizeMB
------------- --------- --------- ------------ ---------------
master        4         1.25      NULL         NULL
model         2.25      0.75      NULL         NULL
msdb          14.75     8.1875    NULL         NULL
tempdb        8         0.5       NULL         NULL
```

Note: was inspired by [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/08/sql-server-find-the-size-of-database-file-find-the-size-of-log-file/)

Comment: I get NULL values on every column using this? any idea as to why?

Comment: if sys.master_files is empty it could be permissions. Min permissions are CREATE DATABASE, ALTER ANY DATABASE, or VIEW ANY DEFINITION (ref: BOL sys.master_files)

Answer (score 24):

Here's a simple, quick and reliable query that will give all database and log file names, sizes and also database statuses (e.g. ONLINE) in a nice, easy to read output:

```
SELECT
    D.name,
    F.Name AS FileType,
    F.physical_name AS PhysicalFile,
    F.state_desc AS OnlineStatus,
    CAST(F.size AS bigint) * 8*1024 AS SizeInBytes,
    CAST((F.size*8.0)/1024/1024 AS decimal(18,3)) AS SizeInGB
FROM 
    sys.master_files F
    INNER JOIN sys.databases D ON D.database_id = F.database_id
ORDER BY SizeInBytes desc
```

Answer (score 8):

All seem overly complicated! Or am I missing something?

Surely all you need is something like:

```
select d.name, case when m.type = 0 then 'Data' else 'Log' end,  m.size * 8 / 1024
from sys.master_files m JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = m.database_id
```

or if you don't want the log:

```
select d.name, m.size * 8 / 1024
from sys.master_files m JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = m.database_id and m.type =0
```

Answer (score 7):

with Total Database size ordered Desc

```
SELECT     
DB_NAME(db.database_id) DatabaseName,     
(CAST(mfrows.RowSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 RowSizeMB,     
(CAST(mflog.LogSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 LogSizeMB, 
(CAST(mfrows.RowSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024/1024+(CAST(mflog.LogSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024/1024 DBSizeG,
(CAST(mfstream.StreamSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 StreamSizeMB,     
(CAST(mftext.TextIndexSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 TextIndexSizeMB 
FROM sys.databases db     
LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, 
                  SUM(size) RowSize 
            FROM sys.master_files 
            WHERE type = 0 
            GROUP BY database_id, type) mfrows 
    ON mfrows.database_id = db.database_id     
LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, 
                  SUM(size) LogSize 
            FROM sys.master_files 
            WHERE type = 1 
            GROUP BY database_id, type) mflog 
    ON mflog.database_id = db.database_id     
LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, 
                  SUM(size) StreamSize 
                  FROM sys.master_files 
                  WHERE type = 2 
                  GROUP BY database_id, type) mfstream 
    ON mfstream.database_id = db.database_id     
LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, 
                  SUM(size) TextIndexSize 
                  FROM sys.master_files 
                  WHERE type = 4 
                  GROUP BY database_id, type) mftext 
    ON mftext.database_id = db.database_id 
       ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
    DB.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN MF.size * 8 / 1024 ELSE 0 END) AS DataFileSizeMB,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN MF.size * 8 / 1024 ELSE 0 END) AS LogFileSizeMB
FROM
    sys.master_files MF
    JOIN sys.databases DB ON DB.database_id = MF.database_id
GROUP BY DB.name
ORDER BY DataFileSizeMB DESC
```

Comment: `GROUP BY DB.name, DB.database_id ORDER BY DB.database_id`  retains table order.

Answer (score 5):

please find more deatils or download the script from below link 
   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SIZE-OF-ALL-DATABASES-IN-0337f6d5#content

```
 DECLARE @spacetable table
 (
 database_name varchar(50) ,
 total_size_data int,
 space_util_data int,
 space_data_left int,
 percent_fill_data float,
 total_size_data_log int,
 space_util_log int,
 space_log_left int,
 percent_fill_log char(50),
 [total db size] int,
 [total size used] int,
 [total size left] int
 )
 insert into  @spacetable
 EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];
 select x.[DATABASE NAME],x.[total size data],x.[space util],x.[total size data]-x.[space util] [space left data],
 x.[percent fill],y.[total size log],y.[space util],
 y.[total size log]-y.[space util] [space left log],y.[percent fill],
 y.[total size log]+x.[total size data] ''total db size''
 ,x.[space util]+y.[space util] ''total size used'',
 (y.[total size log]+x.[total size data])-(y.[space util]+x.[space util]) ''total size left''
  from (select DB_NAME() ''DATABASE NAME'',
 sum(size*8/1024) ''total size data'',sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed'')*8/1024) ''space util''
 ,case when sum(size*8/1024)=0 then ''less than 1% used'' else
 substring(cast((sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed''))*1.0*100/sum(size)) as CHAR(50)),1,6) end ''percent fill''
 from sys.master_files where database_id=DB_ID(DB_NAME())  and  type=0
 group by type_desc  ) as x ,
 (select 
 sum(size*8/1024) ''total size log'',sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed'')*8/1024) ''space util''
 ,case when sum(size*8/1024)=0 then ''less than 1% used'' else
 substring(cast((sum(FILEPROPERTY(name,''SpaceUsed''))*1.0*100/sum(size)) as CHAR(50)),1,6) end ''percent fill''
 from sys.master_files where database_id=DB_ID(DB_NAME())  and  type=1
 group by type_desc  )y'
 select * from @spacetable
 order by database_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplified & Improved version:

```
SELECT
    D.name,
    CAST(SUM(F.size) AS bigint) * 8*1024 AS SizeInBytes,
    CAST(SUM(F.size*8.0)/1024/1024 AS decimal(18,3)) AS SizeInGB
FROM 
    sys.master_files F
    INNER JOIN sys.databases D ON D.database_id = F.database_id
GROUP BY D.name
ORDER BY SizeInBytes desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this page looking for something like this.
Just in case someone comes across this and is interested in only the core user databases, you can use something like this which excludes Master, msdb...

```
SELECT
DB_NAME(db.database_id) DatabaseName,
(CAST(mfrows.RowSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 RowSizeMB,
(CAST(mflog.LogSize AS FLOAT)*8)/1024 LogSizeMB
FROM sys.databases db
LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, SUM(size) RowSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE type = 0 GROUP BY database_id, type) mfrows ON mfrows.database_id = db.database_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT database_id, SUM(size) LogSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE type = 1 GROUP BY database_id, type) mflog ON mflog.database_id = db.database_id
where DB_NAME(db.database_id) not like 'master'
and DB_NAME(db.database_id) not like 'msdb'
and DB_NAME(db.database_id) not like 'model'
and DB_NAME(db.database_id) not like 'tempdb'
and DB_NAME(db.database_id) not like 'Northwind'
and DB_NAME(db.database_id) not like 'ReportServer'
order by DB_NAME(db.database_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#space') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #space

CREATE TABLE #space (
      database_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    , data_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
    , log_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space (database_id, data_used_size, log_used_size)
    SELECT
          DB_ID()
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN space_used END)
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN space_used END)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.[type], space_used = SUM(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8. / 1024)
        FROM sys.database_files s
        GROUP BY s.[type]
    ) t;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT
      d.database_id
    , d.name
    , d.state_desc
    , d.recovery_model_desc
    , t.total_size
    , t.data_size
    , s.data_used_size
    , t.log_size
    , s.log_used_size
FROM (
    SELECT
          database_id
        , log_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , data_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , total_size = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    FROM sys.master_files
    GROUP BY database_id
) t
JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = t.database_id
LEFT JOIN #space s ON d.database_id = s.database_id
ORDER BY t.total_size DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to steal your answer and adapt it for points or anything, but here is another factorization:

```
select d.name, 
    sum(m0.size*8.0/1024) data_file_size_mb, 
    sum(m1.size*8.0/1024) log_file_size_mb 
from sys.databases d
inner join sys.master_files m0 on m0.database_id = d.database_id
inner join sys.master_files m1 on m1.database_id = d.database_id
where m0.type = 0 and m1.type = 1
group by d.name, d.database_id
order by d.database_id
```

Comment: **Mihai Bejenariu's** answer comes to closer to what I attempted here.

Answer (score 0):

A better and quite simpler one

```
SELECT [Database Name] = DB_NAME(database_id),
     [Type] = CASE WHEN Type_Desc = 'ROWS' THEN 'Data File(s)'
               WHEN Type_Desc = 'LOG'  THEN 'Log File(s)'
               ELSE Type_Desc END,
     [Size in MB] = CAST( ((SUM(Size)* 8) / 1024.0) AS DECIMAL(18,2) )
FROM   sys.master_files
--Uncomment if you need to query for a particular database
--WHERE      database_id = DB_ID(‘Database Name’) 
GROUP BY  GROUPING SETS
        (
               (DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc),
               (DB_NAME(database_id))
        ) ORDER BY      DB_NAME(database_id), Type_Desc DESC
```

It will give you size of Data File(s) and Log File(s) separately like below

```
DatabaseName    Type            Size in MB
-------------------------------------------
FMS             Data File(s)    23.00
FMS             Log File(s)     1.50
PointOfSale     Data File(s)    4.00
PointOfSale     Log File(s)     1.25
Union2          Data File(s)    336.00
Union2          Log File(s)     1191.13
SurveyProject   Data File(s)    4.00
SurveyProject   Log File(s)     1.00
```

Comment: That's not the output of two grouping sets.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me very well.

```
    SELECT
        D.name As DbName,
        F.Name AS FullDbName,
        CASE WHEN F.type_desc='ROWS' THEN 'mdf' ELSE 'ldf' END AS FileType,
        F.physical_name AS PhysicalFile,
        CONVERT(DATE,D.create_date) AS CreationDate,
        F.state_desc AS OnlineStatus,
        CAST((F.size*8)/1024 AS VARCHAR(26)) + ' MB' AS FileSize_MB,
        CAST(F.size*8 AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' Bytes' AS FileSize_Bytes,
        CAST(CAST(ROUND((F.size*8)/(1024.0*1024.0),0) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(32)) + ' GB' AS FileSize_GB

    FROM 
        sys.master_files F
        INNER JOIN sys.databases D ON D.database_id = F.database_id

    ORDER BY
         D.name
```

Answer (score 0):

All this examples work fine on most of my database servers.
However if you have 1 server with multiple instances and all those servers those query's give you no result.

For instance the first query gives a result like:

```
name    DataFileSizeMB  LogFileSizeMB
master  NULL    NULL
tempdb  NULL    NULL
model   NULL    NULL
msdb    NULL    NULL
```

So the databases are selected from `sys.databases`, however the table `sys.master_files` seems to be empty or gives no result.

Even a simple query as `select * from sys.master_files` has a result of 0 records.
You don't receive any errors but no records are found.
On my servers with only 1 database instance this works fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I suggest you improve your answer for the next times, have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: [Hava a look here to [how to indent your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300124/13903942)

Answer (score -1):

sometimes **SECURITY** issues prevent from asking for all the db's and you need to query one by one with the db prefix, for those cases i created this dynamic query

```
go
declare @Results table ([Name] nvarchar(max), [DataFileSizeMB] int, [LogFileSizeMB] int);

declare @QaQuery nvarchar(max)
declare @name nvarchar(max)

declare MY_CURSOR cursor 
  local static read_only forward_only
for 
select name from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name not in ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'rdsadmin');

open MY_CURSOR
fetch next from MY_CURSOR into @name
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin 
    if(len(@name)>0)
    begin
        print @name + ' Column Exist'
        set @QaQuery = N'select 
                            '''+@name+''' as Name
                            ,sum(case when type = 0 then size else 0 end) as DataFileSizeMB
                            ,sum(case when type = 1 then size else 0 end) as LogFileSizeMB
                        from ['+@name+'].sys.database_files
                        group by replace(name, ''_log'', '''')';

        insert @Results exec sp_executesql @QaQuery;
    end
  fetch next from MY_CURSOR into @name
end
close MY_CURSOR
deallocate MY_CURSOR

select * from @Results order by DataFileSizeMB desc
go
```